# How can I set a fiscal month callendar, or sort the calendar from 10/Oct to 09/Sept?

Tags: oracle, sorting, fiscal

I need to sort Months by our company's fiscal calendar. As of now i can only be sorted alphabetically, April August,December, Feb..
I need it to sort October-September

```
Fiscal Year Month Name COUNT(DISTINCT CTL_NO) 
2019        April                         437 
2019        December                      707 
2019        February                      600 
2019        January                       730 
2019        March                         542 
2019        November                      745 
2019        October                       955 
2018        April                         600 
2018        August                        902 
2018        December                      728 
2018        February                      593 
2018        January                       745 
2018        July                          812 
2018        June                          704 
2018        March                         671 
2018        May                           589 
2018        November                      590 
2018        October                       769 
2018        September                     810
```

Comment: Id like to add a screenshot but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: Screenshot of what? Screenshots are rarely helpful for pure code questions. Also many people can't access image sites because of firewall restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use a CASE expression to set your sort key. Because your table appears to store months as strings we need to convert them to DATE. Once we have a DATE datatype we can extract the month number, which we can use to sort

```
SELECT Fiscal_Year, Month_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT CTL_NO) 
  FROM SOME_TABLE t
 group by Fiscal_Year, Month_Name
  ORDER BY Fiscal_year
           , CASE TRIM(TO_CHAR(to_date(Month_Name,'Month'), 'MM'))
              WHEN '10' THEN -2
              WHEN '11' THEN -1
              WHEN '12' THEN 0
              ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(to_date(Month_Name,'Month'), 'MM'))
            END
```

This is fine for one-off usage such as a school assignment, but it's not very robust and must be repeated every time you need it.

A much better way is to have a fiscal calendar table which tells you what fiscal year, fiscal month, fiscal week, etc, it is for every calendar day of every year. That's only 365/366 rows per year so there's not a lot of overhead. Tables such as this are commonly populated several years in advance of "now", and the data for past years is left in place for basically ever so that past dates can be looked up and the related fiscal dates determined easily.

Best of luck.

Comment: Is there comprehensive step by step on how to, where to enter this syntax?

Comment: @bobjarvis - your core solution was sound, I've just edited it to fit the data posted by the OP. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: i appreciate the quick help. i don't know what to do with the code yet. i have tried to enter a new calculated field. but i get a syntax error. i admit im definitely enter the code in the wrong place as i don't know how to use oracle.

Comment: @APC: not a problem. :-)

Comment: @Bejohnson - unfortunately there's not much we can do to help with that. If you post your code we can fix syntax errors but that's it.